# Make a Textbox in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am following the [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation and making my own edits as I go along. I am very new to it and have had experience with using Tkinter. There is a Textbox in Tkinter which you an get with the code `Text(window, width=?, height=?, wrap=WORD, background=yellow)`. However in PySimpleGUI with **similar** code: `layout = [[sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')]]` - creates a label. My code is:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Close Window')],
            [sg.Text('This is some text', font='Courier 12', text_color='blue', background_color='green')],
            [sg.Listbox(values=('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), size=(30, 2), key='_LISTBOX_')]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Test', layout).Finalize()
window.Maximize()
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Close Window'): # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

I have attempted using [PySimpleGui: How to enter text in the text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808158/pysimplegui-how-to-enter-text-in-the-text-box) but the Text Box here is actually a list box:

[image: This questions Text Box]

which is nothing like the TextBox I want:

[image: TextBox I want]

The TextBox is surrounded by the red lines. Can someone please help me find the code that will give me the TextBox that I desire?

Comment: Did you try [sg.Multiline](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiline-element).

Comment: Wow it works and is what I need @acw1668 . Could you potentially answer the question and also show example code of how I can get a variable from it? From the tutorial it looks as if the whole window is read so how am I supposed to draw separate variables from separate areas from it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want?

Comment: @acw1668 in the tutorial you get an input with the code `event, values = window.read()`.  When you have multiple inputs in your window how do you separate them?

Comment: You can assign a `key` to each widget and use this key to identify the data you want.  For example, `sg.Multiline(..., key='textbox')`, then you can use `values['textbox']` to get the content of the `sg.Multiline`.

Comment: Thx @acw1668 . Wanna answer so I can give you a tick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sg.Multiline(...)` which is `Text` widget of tkinter.

To get the content of the `sg.Multiline`, you can assign an unique `key` to it and use this `key` to get its content in the `values` dict.

Below is an example based on your code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Close Window')],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(30, 5), key='textbox')]]  # identify the multiline via key option

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Test', layout).Finalize()
#window.Maximize()
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Close Window'): # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered in the textbox:')
    print(values['textbox'])  # get the content of multiline via its unique key

window.close()
```